# Remove page title in ods pdf

Tags: pdf, graph, sas

I am using SAS 9.3.
My goal is to create a pdf file with 2 graphs on each page.
I got partial success with this code:

```
data mydata;
   var1=1;
   var2=2;
run;

%macro pic;
   %do i=1 %to 6;
      proc sgplot data=mydata;
         title "Title &i";
         vbar var1 / response=var2;
      run;
   %end;
%mend pic;

ods pdf file = "&folder\test.pdf" STARTPAGE=NEVER style=SASweb; 
%pic;
ods pdf close;
```

However, the problem is that after page 2, SAS decides to automatically use my graph title as a page title. The double title takes space and look stupid. How to get rid of this page title? Why it doesn't appear on the first page?

**How do I keep the graph title but get rid of the page title?**

Edit: I can fit two plots per page by resizing the graphs with this statement:

```
ods graphics on / width=580px;
```

But what I really need is to get rid of that double title.

I have tried to specify

```
title;
```

before the plot but it doesn't help. 
Also

```
Options noproctitle;
```

doesn't get me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to take out the TITLE.  Instead, use an INSET positioned on the top to give you the equivalent of a TITLE, inside the graph.  (If you were using GTL, I'd suggest an `EntryTitle`, but you're not.)

It's not exactly identical, but it gets the idea across.  You can do better using GTL with ENTRYTITLE.  You can also remove the frame around the axis with a style template (altering the wall borders, I believe).

```
data mydata;
    var1=1;
    var2=2;
run;

%macro pic;
%do i=1 %to 6;
proc sgplot data=mydata;
    inset "Title &i";
    vbar var1 / response=var2;
    yaxis offsetmax=.1;  *to leave some room for the inset;
run;
%end;
%mend;

ods pdf file = "&folder\test.pdf" STARTPAGE=NEVER style=SASweb; 
%pic;
ods pdf close;
```

Comment: Thanks. This gets it done. I also specified `/ POSITION = TOP BORDER TEXTATTRS=(size=14pt)` in the Inset statement to make it more visible. I still do wonder why SAS insist adding those page titles if I use title in the plot.

Comment: Because you're not using title "in" the plot. Title is always a global statement; SGPLOT just borrows it.  I'm not sure why it's inconsistent between page1 and page2; if you want to find that out, my best recommendation is to post on communities.sas.com in either the data visualization or the ODS forum, and perhaps one of the devs can explain the difference (Cynthia@SAS might be the best to answer that, but it's equally possible Sanjay/Dan would know).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the title statement in your `proc sgplot` to the below worked for me:

```
%if &i=1 %then %str(title "Title &i";);
%else %str(title;);
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: No this doesn't help. This just removes titles from all my pictures except the first one. I still need to include picture titles but no page titles. I tried to clarify my question.